# Apache + php + php-fpm I'm getting the proxy_fcgi:error] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, webserver

Apache+ php + php-fpm
trying to deploy webserver using ec2 with apache html5, css , javascript, php and Mysql

[This is the error i'm getting from /var/log/apache2/error.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmdF6.png)
[Apache mysite configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Udb.png)
[This is my website whenener i entered a username an password it gives me error file not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diEYL.png)
[The error that it gives me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoHWY.png)
i have been searching for days but did not find any solution....Any solution????

trying to deploy webserver using ec2 with apache html5, css , javascript, php and Mysql

i have been searching for days but did not find any solution....Any solution????

Comment: Please Edit your question and provide the code and error messages **at text** rather than images.